# COUNTIF condition to compare values within the counting range

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I´m currently collaborating in the creation of a tool and I´m having the following problem:
I need to count the values of a list of train arrival times that have a difference lower than 2 minutes with the next or previous arrival.
For Example, if the list of arrival times is

```
1-08:00 /
2-08:12 /
3-08:15 /
4-08:16 /
5-08:19 /
6-08:23 /
7-08:24 /
8-08:28 /
...
```

The result of this should be 2 (or 4), given that the time between trains 3 and 4, and trains 6 and 7 is lower than 2 minutes.

Is there any way of doing this with a formula?

Comment: Have you try something ? Post it!

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMPRODUCT with offset ranges:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$8-$B$1:$B$7<=2/(60*24)))
```

[image]